# Exception parsing string to Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I cannot see why this code is failing:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    try {
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        Date d = sdf.parse("202003290230");
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the exception `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date`.

If I set `sdf.setLenient(true)` then it works, but the time in the object Date returned is '03:30' and not '02:30'.

Can someone explain me what's going on in here? Thanks.

Comment: Daylight Saving Time. On 2020-03-29 the clock jumped a hour forward from 1:59 to 3:00 so that there never was any time 2:xx

Comment: You have to be kidding me! did they change the time that day? This was making me crazy! I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: hahaha this post just made my day. I can totally understand your frustration, bro! :))

Comment: I wasted two hours trying to figure this out, and the OH MIGHTY GOD SPIDERS saw it in 1 minute. ;)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: And never swallow exceptions, especially not in tests. Or in production code. Or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

As OH GOD SPIDERS noted in a comment your real problem is that that time doesn’t exist in you default time zone because of the *spring forward*, the transition to summer time (DST).

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. The short-sighted answer is: use `LocalDateTime` from java.time.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmm");
    String dateTimeString = "202003290230";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, formatter);
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

Output is:

> 2020-03-29T02:30

A `LocalDateTime` is a date and time without time zone. So it doesn’t discover that the time doesn’t exist in your time zone. The result is 2:30 as in the string.

### Detecting a non-existing time

It seems you’re in a Central European time zone or some other time zone where summer time began on the last Sunday in March, and the clocks were turned forward from 2 to 3 (AM). So there was no 2:30. Supposing that you want to know, you may do:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zone);
    if (zdt.toLocalDateTime().equals(ldt)) {
        System.out.println("The time " + zdt + " exists");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The time " + ldt + " does not exist in " + zone);
    }
```

> The time 2020-03-29T02:30 does not exist in Europe/Paris

java.time too gives you 3:30 instead of 2:30 when given a time in the spring gap. So when converting back from `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime` in this case we don’t get the same time again, which we use for detecting the non-existing time.

I further recommend that you use `ZonedDateTime` for past dates and times, not `LocalDateTime`.

### Java 6?

> This project is made with Java6 and the company doesn't want to update
> it, …

java.time has been backported, and I have tested the code above with the backport, ThreeTen Backport, see the link at the bottom.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310). I’m unsure whether the very latest release of ThreeTen Backport works with Java 6 or only with Java 7(+). If this is an issue, go back a few releases and find one that works with Java 6 too.
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Don’t use SimpleDateFormat

The date and time classes you were trying to use, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are poorly designed and long outdated. In your case they showed a behaviour that depends on a time zone that isn’t present in the code at all, which is quite confusing. I recommend that you don’t use those classes.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This project is made with Java6 and the company doesn't want to update it, however in modern projects java.time is the way to go with Java8+.

Comment: @maqjav You can uses java,time with Java 6 too. See my edit.

Comment: @maqjav If, at the end of 2020, your employer doesn’t want to upgrade from Java 6, you should be out looking for a new employer, not a new solution.